# How can I use PineScript to trade with the latest chart at 14:50?

Tags: session, time, pine-script

The default in pine script is that the order is executed at the next bar after the buy or sell is made. I want the order to be executed at 14:50 on the same day. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `process_orders_on_close`  property of the `strategy()` function to `true` if you want your orders to be placed on bar close.

Then you can use the `hour` and `minute` built-variables to figure out the time and execute your order.

Alternatively, you can define a trading session and use it in your code.

```
timeAllowed = input("1200-1500", "Allowed hours", input.session)

// Check to see if we are in allowed hours using session info on all 7 days of the week.
timeIsAllowed = time(timeframe.period, timeAllowed + ":1234567")
```